# What's the mechanism of UIView Initial Display in Object C

Tags: ios, uiview

I am a newbie learning "iPad and iPhone Application Development" course. In the demo of lecture 5, we have some code like this

```
#import "HappinessViewController.h"
#import "FaceView.h"

@interface HappinessViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet FaceView *faceView;
@end

@implementation HappinessViewController

@synthesize happiness = _happiness;
@synthesize faceView = _faceView;


-(void) setHappiness:(int)happiness
{
    _happiness = happiness;
    [self.faceView setNeedsDisplay];
}


-(void)setFaceView:(FaceView *)faceView
{
    _faceView = faceView;
    NSLog(@"set FaceView invoked");
    [self.faceView addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]        
 initWithTarget:self.faceView action:@selector(pinch:)]];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

in method "-(void)setFaceView:(FaceView *)faceView", I wonder it might be something similar to event listener in javascript. But I also want to know
when the event listener was bound. So I add "NSLog(@"set FaceView invoked");". It turns out that this setter function was invoked once I run this program which makes me really very confused. So I am wondering how "setFaceView" is invoked at the very beginning?

By the way, FaceView is a subclass of UIView and faceView is the only instance of FaceView class. And also I try to add "NSLog(@"set happiness invoked");" in method setHappiness, this 
is not invoked at the very beginning of program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have faceView bound to a view in a NIB or a Storyboard, then `-setFaceView:` is called when the NIB is loaded or the view controller is loaded by the Storyboard.

`-setFaceView:` is the setter for the faceView property. Whenever `self.faceView = …` is done, it's `-setFaceView:` that gets called.

Comment: thanks. is this because faceView is an IBOutlet. It is a weak pointer. First, Class FaceView instantiates , then set faceView which is an pointer pointing to that. Am I guessing right?

Comment: @zhouwubai Yes, faceView can be set in Interface Builder (IB) because it's marked as IBOutlet. As far as it being weak, self.faceView will be retained by self.view when it's added as a subview, so there it no reason for it to be strong. If self.faceView was being removed and re-added to self.view, then it would need to be strong.